# Prove that random variable is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

After a question I asked concerning my failure to prove that a random variable is a stopping time I come to propose another proof that I hope is better.

We consider $X$ a continuous process with its natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. We consider the following stopping Time

$$
\tau(\omega)=\inf\left\{t : X_t(\omega)\in A \right\}
$$

Where $A$ is a closed set. Here is my new attempt :

$$
\left\{\tau(\omega) \leq t\right\} = \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t], d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\}
$$

Now we notice that for $\omega\in \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t], d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\}$ we have an $s\in[0,t]$ such that $d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0$. By continuity of the process and of the distance function to a closed set we can find $s_n\subset[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ such that $d(X_s(\omega),A)=\lim_{n\to\infty} d(X_{s_n}(\omega),A)$. In other words for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $d(X_{s_n}(\omega),A) \leq d(X_{s}(\omega),A) +\epsilon = \epsilon$ which shows that for all $n\geq N$ we have $d(X_{s_n}(\omega),A)=0$.

Thus

$$
\left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t],  d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0\right\}\subset \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\}
$$

The reverse inclusion is also satisfied as we can see so we have

$$
\left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t] , d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\} = \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\} = \cup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\left\{ \omega : d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\}
$$

But the sets $\left\{ \omega : d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\}$ are in $\mathcal{F}_s\subset\mathcal{F}_t$ ($X_s$ is adapted and the distance function is continuous). So it is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable as a countable union of measurable sets.

I would like to have some comments on this please so do not hesitate, thank you a lot !

---

Mason’s answer shows that my proof is wrong because I introduced a dependence in $\epsilon$ of my $N$. Here is another attempt to show the following inclusion

$$
\left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t],  d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0\right\}\subset \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0 \right\}
$$

Which is the central point to end the proof.

The  idea is to relax the condition to have $d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0$. Indeed we have the following equality which could be usefull to do my $\epsilon-\delta$ use of the continuity of $X$.

$$
\left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t],  d(X_s(\omega),A) = 0\right\} = \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t], \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, d(X_s(\omega),A)< \frac{1}{n} \right\}
$$

Now take $\omega\in\left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t], \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, d(X_s(\omega),A)< \frac{1}{n} \right\}$. Let $n$ be fixed. Consider $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n} - d(X_s(\omega),A)>0$. By continuity of $X$ and the distance function we have that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $u\in [0,t]$ satisfying $\lvert u-s\rvert<\delta$ we have $\lvert d(X_u(\omega),A) - d(X_s(\omega),A)\rvert<\epsilon$. This implies that for such $u$ we have $d(X_u(\omega),A)<\frac{1}{n}$. But there exists rationals in $[0,t]$ satisfying $\lvert u-s\rvert<\delta$.

So we conclude that for this particular $\omega$, there exists $s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ such that $d(X_s(\omega),A)<\frac{1}{n}$. This shows that

$$
 \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t], \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, d(X_s(\omega),A)< \frac{1}{n} \right\}\subset  \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, d(X_s(\omega),A)< \frac{1}{n} \right\}
$$

The reverse inclusion being direct we have

$$
\left\{\tau(\omega) \leq t\right\} = \left\{ \omega : \exists s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, d(X_s(\omega),A)< \frac{1}{n} \right\} = \cup_{s\in [0,t]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{ \omega : d(X_s(\omega),A)< \frac{1}{n} \right\}\in\mathcal{F}_t
$$

Using the fact that $X$ is adapted and the distance function is continuous.

Comment: Did I do something wrong to explain the downvote please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N$ depends on $\varepsilon$, so your proof is wrong. Indeed, it is possible for a continuous process to enter a closed set at exactly one point. Think of $X_t = |t - \pi|$, which enters $A = (-\infty, 0]$ at only $t = \pi$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed it was a big mistake I did not see. Have you any idea to prove this result ?

Comment: I tried to correct my proof in order to make dissapear this incoherence in my use of the continuity of $X$.

Comment: My answer shows that the inclusion you are trying to prove is not true. I would use $ \inf\{ d(X_s, A) : s \in [0, t]\} = \inf\{ d(X_s, A) : s \in [0, t] \cap \mathbb{Q}\}$, which follows from continuity of $d$ and $X$.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. I have difficulty understanding your example and your argument then. Based on the latter, I understood that I could always find a sequence of rationals (of limit $\pi$) which I can always make as close to $0$ as I want by choosing my rank carefully. And from this point of view, it seems to me to be the same idea as what you propose with the infinimum in the end.